# how to increase preview camera quality in ARCore

Tags: java, android, android-camera, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm using ARCore in my android project. It has one activity, MainActivity.java and one CustomArFragment.java.

The problem is that the camera quality is very low. how can I increase the camera preview resolution. In future , I need the recognize the text using camera and having such low quality, its difficult to recognize. I am not able to find the solution on google. Tried many things but got no success. Anyone please tell how to increase camera quality. I'm totally new in AR and android field.

Thanks :)

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomArFragment arFragment;
private TextView textView;
private AugmentedImageDatabase aid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

arFragment = (CustomArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

findViewById(R.id.registeredBtn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        return;
    }
    registeredImage();
});


}


private void registeredImage() {
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/db.imgdb");
try {

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.earth);
    aid.addImage("earth",bitmap);
    aid.serialize(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "image Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
Collection<AugmentedImage> images = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
for(AugmentedImage image : images){
    if(image.getTrackingMethod() == AugmentedImage.TrackingMethod.FULL_TRACKING){
        if(image.getName().equals("lion")){
            textView.setText("LION is visible");
        }
        else if(image.getName().equals("download")){
            textView.setText("download is visible");
        }
        else{
            textView.setText("Nothing is visible till now");
        }
        Log.d("Value of textView : "," " + textView.getText());
    }
    Log.d("Value of textView1 : "," " + textView.getText());
  }
 }

 public void loadDB(Session session, Config config){
//InputStream dbStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.imagedb);
try {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/db.imgdb");
    FileInputStream dbStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    aid = AugmentedImageDatabase.deserialize(session, dbStream);
    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);
    session.configure(config);
    Log.d("TotalImages"," :  " + aid.getNumImages());

}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

CustomArFragment.java

```
public class CustomArFragment extends ArFragment {
@Override
protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session){
    getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
    Config config = new Config(session);
    config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.loadDB(session,config);
    this.getArSceneView().setupSession(session);
    return config;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added some info regarding a similar topic in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190820/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-high-res-image-while-using-arcore). But answering yours, check what [CameraConfig](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/CameraConfig) is used by default (use [getCameraConfig()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#getCameraConfig()) on the Session). Then you can get the one that is of your interest (high GPU texture size) through [getSupportedCameraConfigs()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#getSupportedCameraConfigs(com.google.ar.core.CameraConfigFilter)) and configure the Session with it through [setCameraConfig](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#setCameraConfig(com.google.ar.core.CameraConfig)).

Reading your question again, if you need in the future to recognize some text on the image, you might want to get a higher CPU image instead of GPU texture size. You can still use CameraConfig to check that and choose your favorite, but keep in mind that higher CPU images decreases the performance quite a bit. You might want to check my answer in the question I mentioned earlier.

EDIT: Use this code snippet to check the CameraConfig being used and adapt it to your needs:

```
Session session = new Session(requireActivity());

// ...

Size selectedSize = new Size(0, 0);
CameraConfig selectedCameraConfig = null;

CameraConfigFilter filter = new CameraConfigFilter(session);
List<CameraConfig> cameraConfigsList = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(filter);
for (CameraConfig currentCameraConfig : cameraConfigsList) {
    Size cpuImageSize = currentCameraConfig.getImageSize();
    Size gpuTextureSize = currentCameraConfig.getTextureSize();
    Log.d("TAG", "CurrentCameraConfig CPU image size:" + cpuImageSize + " GPU texture size:" + gpuTextureSize);

    // Adapt this check to your needs
    if (gpuTextureSize.getWidth() > selectedSize.getWidth()) {
        selectedSize = gpuTextureSize;
        selectedCameraConfig = currentCameraConfig;
    }
}

Log.d("TAG", "Selected CameraConfig CPU image size:" + selectedCameraConfig.getImageSize() + " GPU texture size:" + selectedCameraConfig.getTextureSize());
session.setCameraConfig(selectedCameraConfig);

// ...

// Don't forget to configure the session afterwards
session.configure(config);
```

Comment: Hi @Pau Guillamon , Thanks for the answer.  I added below lines to CustomArFragment.java :                                                                  
       CameraConfigFilter filter = new CameraConfigFilter(session);
        CameraConfig[] cameraConfigList = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(filter).toArray(new CameraConfig[0]);
        session.setCameraConfig(cameraConfigList[0]);                                                                But it is not working. Still blurry.

Comment: Iterate the list you get from getSupportedCameraConfigs(), don't do toArray(new CameraConfig[0]);, and choose the one that matches your requirement, maybe search for the higher GPU texture image. In order to understand this better, list ALL cameraConfigs in the log so you can see what is available on your device, you can later decide what to do depending on the values you get.

Comment: Without toArray(new CameraConfig[0]) giving me the error. So, I changed that line to :        List<CameraConfig> cameraConfigList = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(filter);

Comment: When i iterate CameraConfigList, im getting following 3 values :                                                          1)com.google.ar.core.CameraConfig@fcb2ebd  ,                                                                              2)com.google.ar.core.CameraConfig@4eeacb2  ,                                                                        3)com.google.ar.core.CameraConfig@5e9f403

Comment: I found out the problem but i didn't know why its happening...whatever CameraConfig i'm setting, it is not getting set.                                                                                                              CameraConfigFilter filter = new CameraConfigFilter(session);
        List<CameraConfig> cameraConfigList = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(filter);
        
        session.setCameraConfig(cameraConfigList.get(i));  (0<= i <<=2)
        Log.d("gggg11",""+session.getCameraConfig());     // this line always printing same cameraConfig whatever I set.

Comment: Hi @Pau Guillamon, please help me out.

Comment: I have added a code snippet to my answer. I hope that helps!

Comment: Now, I am getting the ImageSize = "2048*1536" and TextureSize="2048*1536". But still camera  is so blurry that i  cannot read the text. Can't Camera  quality be improved?

Comment: I set the CameraConfig, that has ImageSize = "1296*960" and TextureSize="2048*1536" and now its working fine. Now the only problem is that, how would I know what CameraConfig i need to set on any mobile device?

Comment: Glad to hear it works! So depending on your needs, if it's only for rendering the image then you can probably just look for the highest TextureSize and keeping the lowest CPU image Size. As mentioned, higher CPU image size have an impact on performance. So if you don't need the CPU image try to keep that to the minimum.

Comment: Hi @Pau Guillamon, Please have a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181806/how-to-capture-image-with-arcore-camera-and-save-it-to-arcore-database) link.