# How to capture image with ARCore camera and save it to ARCore database

Tags: java, android, android-camera, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm using ARcore in my project. There is only one activity ie. MainActivity.java and 1 CustomArFragment.java class. In mainActivity.java, there is one button ***Registered Image*** , whose function is to capture the image and saved that image in ARCore database. Below is the code of MainActivity.java.

MainActivity.java  :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomArFragment arFragment;
private AugmentedImageDatabase aid;
private Frame frame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arFragment = (CustomArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
    

    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

    findViewById(R.id.registeredBtn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            return;
        }
        registeredImage();
    });
}


private void registeredImage() {

    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/db.imgdb");
    Frame CurrFrame = frame;
    Image currentImage;
    try { 
        currentImage = CurrFrame.acquireCameraImage();  //getting captured Image in YUV_420_888 format
        }
    } catch (NotYetAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // bitmap = Convert this YUV_420_888 image to bitmp
        idx = aid.addImage("earth",bitmap);  
        aid.serialize(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "image Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    Collection<AugmentedImage> images = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
    for(AugmentedImage image : images){
        // Some Code
    }
}
}
```

**onUpdate** function will be called for every update in ArSceneView. So in order to get the captured image when user clicked on **registered image** button, I'm assigning that frame(global object) in currFrame object(using in registeredImage function), and then using CurrFrame.acquireCameraImage() to get the image in YUV_420_888 format.

My query is, how to save this acquired YUV_420_888 format image in ARCore dataBase(should i need to convert this image format to bitmap??). I tried first to convert this image to in .jpg format and then in bitmap but when this image add in database, the app gets crash. I'm new in Android and ARcore. Please help.

Thanks:)